# Remove duplicate match from string by regular expression

Tags: php, regex, arrays, preg-match-all, array-unique

```
<?php

function get_video() {

$stripper = "Content...[video=1], content...content...[video=2],
             content...content...content...[video=1], no more...";

preg_match_all("/\[video=(.+?)\]/smi", $stripper, $search);  

$unique = array_unique($search[0]);

$total = count($unique);     
for($i=0; $i < $total; $i++) 
{    
  $vid = $search[1][$i]; 
  if ($vid > 0) 
  {      
    $random_numbers = rand(1, 1000);
    $video_id = $vid."_".$random_numbers;
    $stripper = str_replace($search[0][$i], $video_id, $stripper); 
  } 
} 
return $stripper;
}  

echo get_video();   
?>
```

I want to remove duplicate [video=1] in $stripper, this is the result i need:

```
Content...1_195, content...content...2_963, 
content...content...content..., no more...
```

I am using array_unique() function to remove the duplicate array. From my code above, if i print_r($unique), the duplicate array has been removed:

```
Array ( [0] => [video=1] [1] => [video=2] )
```

But if i echo get_video(), the duplicate [video=1] still exist:

```
Content...1_195, content...content...2_963, 
content...content...content...1_195([video=1]), no more...
```

I can't figure out why!!! :(

Demo: http://eval.in/7178

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove duplicates execute a `preg_replace_callback` and replace the duplicate one by "".  Use the following code just before your `preg_match_all` call,

```
$hash = array();
$stripper = preg_replace_callback("/\[video=(.+?)\]/smi",function($m){
    global $hash;
    if(isset($hash[$m[0]]))
        return "";
    else{
        $hash[$m[0]]=1;
        return $m[0];
    }
}, $stripper);
```

See http://eval.in/7185

Answer (score 1):

You can try this;

```
$stripper = "Content...[video=1], content...content...[video=2],
                content...content...content...[video=1], no more...";
preg_match_all("/\[video=([^\]]*)/i", $stripper, $matches);
$result = array();
foreach ($matches[1] as $k => $v) {
    if (!isset($result[$v])) {
        $result[$v] = $v;
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

Outputs;

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
)
```